# circuit_build_no_more_hops: Bug: 2-hop circuit 0x7fd6935ce4c0 with purpose 5 has no guard state

Tags: circuit, stem

For research, I need to create custom circuits using stem.
I ran code, but a warning occurred in Tor application:

```
[warn] circuit_build_no_more_hops: Bug: 2-hop circuit 0x7fd6935ce4c0 with purpose 5 has no guard state (on Tor 0.3.5.5-alpha )
```

This error did not change whether you chaned Tor versions of Docker environments.

Of course, I changed the number of hops but it was useless.

I tried "bine" instead of "stem", but the result did not change.

Code:

```
from stem.control import Controller
with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
  controller.authenticate("my_password")
  print controller.extend_circuit('0', ['FC9AC8EA0160D88BCCFDE066940D7DD9FA45495B','6CADB707B2E0170B5F13557E42DB7E5C151CC0BC'],await_build = True)
  controller.set_conf('__LeaveStreamsUnattached', '1')
```

Error response:

```
~/D/tor-0.3.5.5-alpha ❯❯❯ ./src/app/tor 
Dec 11 02:14:35.867 [notice] Tor 0.3.5.5-alpha running on Darwin with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2q, Zlib 1.2.5, Liblzma 5.2.3, and Libzstd N/A.
Dec 11 02:14:35.868 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Dec 11 02:14:35.868 [notice] This version is not a stable Tor release. Expect more bugs than usual.
Dec 11 02:14:35.871 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc".
Dec 11 02:14:35.875 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Dec 11 02:14:35.875 [notice] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Dec 11 02:14:35.875 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Dec 11 02:14:35.875 [notice] Opened Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Dec 11 02:14:35.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/local/share/tor/geoip.
Dec 11 02:14:36.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/local/share/tor/geoip6.
Dec 11 02:14:36.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Dec 11 02:14:39.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "default"
Dec 11 02:14:39.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server
Dec 11 02:14:39.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
Dec 11 02:14:40.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
Dec 11 02:14:42.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
Dec 11 02:15:07.000 [notice] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
Dec 11 02:15:09.000 [warn] circuit_build_no_more_hops: Bug: 2-hop circuit 0x7fd6935ce4c0 with purpose 5 has no guard state (on Tor 0.3.5.5-alpha )
```

torrc setting:

```
ControlPort 9051
CookieAuthentication 1
HashedControlPassword 16:E600ADC1B52C80BB6022A0E999A7734571A451EB6AE50FED489B72E3DF
```

Please create a custom circuit and tell me if there are samples you can use.
Or please also tell me what is wrong.